# How to export lines without image in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, opencv

I'm using the Houghlines method to create hough lines from my image, which returns the intended result. Except I want to export the hough lines without the original import image. How to?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

in_path  = 'my/tif/file'
out_path = 'my/output/tif/file'

gray = cv2.imread(in_path)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('edges.tif',edges)
minLineLength=10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=3,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=20)

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(gray, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imwrite(out_path,gray)
```

Is it possible to export the lines as a vector or on a plain image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First  create an image with black pixels having the same shape and datatype of the original image. Then draw the detected lines on this image.

```
black = np.zeros_like(gray)
```

Here `black` is an array where all elements are 0. In other words it is a black image having the same shape and datatype as `gray`.

```
cv2.line(black, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imwrite(out_path, black)
```

The right way would be to first draw the lines using `cv21.line()` within the for loop. After this proceed to save the image using `cv2.imwrite()`.

Here the complete code you can run:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

in_path  = 'my/tif/file'
out_path = 'my/output/tif/file'

gray = cv2.imread(in_path)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('edges.tif',edges)
minLineLength=10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=3,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=20)

black = np.zeros_like(gray) 

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(black, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (255, 0, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite(out_path,gray)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a small addition, in the entire code you posted it should be 'cv2.imwrite(out_path,gray)' , like you said earlier in the answer.

Comment: @Squaree Great!